# Add Markdown Citations using Pandoc

Tags: bibliographies, citing, pandoc, markdown

I am going through a process of converting all our code documentation from LaTeX to Markdown. I figured that my best bet was to use Pandoc. We have developed our own flavor of Markdown so I will need to go in and edit by hand some of the freshly converted markdown.

I am having trouble producing proper citations within my markdown. The current command I am using seems to be "hardcoding" the citations in without markdown short cuts (ie. (Hammond et. all 2015) vs [@cite:Hammond]). I have the .bib files. Is there a way to make this work?

Code I am currently running to convert from LaTeX to MD

`pandoc --ascii -f latex -t gfm --filter=pandoc-citeproc -o test.md input.tex`

Code I have tested but still doesn't work

`pandoc -s -V biblio-files=../../../../../../doc/content/bib/*.bib --filter=pandoc-citeproc -f latex -t gfm -o test.md input.tex`

How can I get it to produce a dynamic markdown citation instead of hardcoding it in?

#### Sample TeX File

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\title{My Article}
\author{Nobody Jr.}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said Nobody ~\cite{Nobody06}.

\bibliography{name}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

#### Sample Bib File

```
@misc{ Nobody06,
       author = "Nobody Jr",
       title = "My Article",
       year = "2006" }
```

#### Sample Output Markdown File

```
Blablabla said Nobody  (Jr 2006).

<div id="refs" class="references">

<div id="ref-Nobody06">

Jr, Nobody. 2006. “My Article.”

</div>

</div>
```

#### What I want

```
Blablabla said Nobody [@Nobody06].
```

Comment: Can you share more details about what exactly you are doing? Would it be possible to create a short example `.tex` document (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and show the resulting `.md` file?

Comment: @moewe See my above edits. Not quite sure what more there is to explain. The way I'm currently converting it is hardcoding the citations in, but I want it to output the markdown syntax for citations like how it does for all images and tables.

Comment: Does `gfm` support citations? Playing around with http://pandoc.org/try/?text=%5Cdocumentclass%7Barticle%7D%0A%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0ALorem~%5Ccite%7BNobody06%7D.%0A%0A%5Cbibliographystyle%7Bplain%7D%0A%5Cbibliography%7Bname%7D%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D&from=latex&to=markdown suggests that `pandoc --from latex --to markdown` gives the desired output, but `pandoc --from latex --to gfm` does not.

Comment: That does work like how I want it, but now I've lost support to correctly render my markdown tables and images. I'm trying to convert with the least amount of manual work as possible but short of actually creating a PR to submit our flavor of markdown as a pandoc option IDK if it's possible to do what I really want.

Comment: Sorry, that's all I can say. I have no idea about pandoc. But if `gfm` has no official support for citations it is not at all unreasonable of pandoc to export the citation as hard-coded text. As long as pandoc does not allow you to cherry-pick bits of markdown syntax you seem to be caught between the devil and the deep blue sea.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer thanks to @moewe's help. Apparently Github Flavored Markdown does not support short-linking citations but pandoc's own markdown does. A 2nd problem arose, in that, pandoc's markdown does not support `pipe_tables` by default. Running the below code gave me in text citations and also played well with all the other Markdown requirements I needed:

```
pandoc --ascii -f latex -t markdown-multiline_tables-simple_tables --atx-headers -o test.md test.tex
```